# Oracle sql return rows with different columns values only

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables table a and table b with exact same structure. I would like to return the columns with different values: Could somebody tell me how to achieve the below

for eg;

Table A

```
ID, Fname, Lname, Age 
1   Mike   Smith  10
```

Table B

```
ID, Fname, Lname, Age  
1   Mike   Smith  20
```

My result should be

```
different_columns

Age
```

Comment: is id always the same ? And what if two different column values are there ? You want them both ? Or three ?

Answer (score 2):

```
select id,
       listagg(diff_col, ', ') within group(order by diff_col) as diff_cols
  from (select a.id, 'fname' as diff_col
          from tablea a
          left join tableb b
            on a.id = b.id
           and a.fname = b.fname
         where b.id is null
        union all
        select a.id, 'lname'
          from tablea a
          left join tableb b
            on a.id = b.id
           and a.lname = b.lname
         where b.id is null
        union all
        select a.id, 'age'
          from tablea a
          left join tableb b
            on a.id = b.id
           and a.age = b.age
         where b.id is null)
 group by id
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/daeaf/4/0

(I added an ID # 2 with a different age AND lname, for illustration)

Another way of doing this is a giant case statement but I would prefer the above as it's easier to tack on more conditions should your actual table have more than 3 columns with which you are doing this test.

If you don't mind having one column per column check (see next fiddle) this might be more ideal for checking that many columns. I'm not sure there is an easier way; you'd have to tack on a bunch of ORs to the WHERE clause and a bunch more case statements for each column comparison.

```
select a.id,
       case when a.fname <> b.fname then 'X' end as fname,
       case when a.lname <> b.lname then 'X' end as lname,
       case when a.age <> b.age then 'X' end as age
  from tablea a
  join tableb b
    on a.id = b.id
 where a.fname <> b.fname
    or a.lname <> b.lname
    or a.age <> b.age
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/daeaf/7/0

(this shows an X if there is a difference in the indicated column, otherwise nothing)

Comment: Actually, my table has lot of columns (more than 100). Is there any other approach to solve this? Thank you for solving this

Comment: @user1751356 you can use conditional aggregation (see second query I just posted in my edit) if you don't mind having the result for each column being represented by one column. It might be a little easier.

Comment: Yes, i don't need the result to be represented in 1 column. Then what is the easiest approach

Comment: Sorry. Please ignore the previous comment. Thanks alot

Comment: @user1751356 it's up to you, in my first query when you look at the inline view you'll notice 3 individual queries connected by unions. One for each column. If you have 97 more columns, you'd have to have 97 more of those. If you choose the 2nd query, you'd have to add 97 case statements, and 97 OR conditions to the WHERE clause. Personally with 100 columns I would use the second query, and it would probably run faster.

Comment: @user1751356 you actually don't need the aggregation, see my edit. Still will be cumberson having 100 case statements but I don't see any way around that.

Comment: Hi, I got another thought. Basically although the table has 100 columns most of the values are zeros. So i would like to query one table, let's say table a based on an id value and return all the columns with non-zero values. Then if I get like 15-20 colunmns, non-zero columns from table A. I will use only those columns for my case statement. Table A is the main table which has good data from prod. Table B is test data which we are comparing with table A (both structures are same)

Comment: @user1751356 if you have excel handy you can use a formula to put together a query consisting of 100 unions to identify the non-zero columns, see http://shwivelin.synology.me:5000/fbsharing/sefCjg4O . Grab the column list from the all_tab_cols dictionary as shown in the file. You could use a similar approach to assembling the case statements for the final query as well.

Comment: Wow, that's actually pretty cool and very fast. I did not understand the purpose of rownum in your excel doc.

Comment: @user1751356 it limits the result to one row, if you ran the inner query (without where rownum = 1 on the outside) you would have 'fname' listed 2000 times if, for instance, it had 2000 non-zero values. In that doc the query is for finding the columns with at least one non-zero value, the rownum thing would not be relevant if you use the same approach but for the final query against your table (using the columns identified as having non-zero values in this query)

Answer (score 0):

If you `union` both tables and group by `id`, then you'll know that any group `having count(*) > 1` has at least 1 column that's different (since `union` automatically removes duplicates).

In order to determine which column is different, you can use `count(distinct column_name)` to see which columns have more than 1 distinct value.

```
select id,
    count(distinct fname) fname,
    count(distinct lname) lname,
    count(distinct age) age
from (
    select * from tablea
    union
    select * from tableb
) t1 group by id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Actually your suggestion also helped me. Thank you for the response.